# Can I make window.postrender = function run the window.onload = function again?

Tags: javascript, onload

So I make pages that are contained in a sort of player. Every 10-45 seconds the player runs a postrender function that calls a bunch of functions outside of my page, but I can add in other functions to call. So my question is how would I make it so when the postrender is called by the player my onload function also fires so my page resets back to the starting position? This way in the loop it will be fresh every time and any interactions from the previous person will go away.

Here is an example of how the code looks now.

```
window.postrender = function() {
//: I can put any additional functions in here
$('#splash').removeClass('hidden');
};

window.onload = function initial() {
//: All of my default starting code
};
```

Comment: Just call your `onload` function... Define your `initial` function somewhere else and put `initial()` in your `.postrender` function.

Comment: So `window.postrender = function() {initial();};` then `function intitial() {"code"};` then `window.onload = function() {initial();};` causes one of my plugins to tell me I have a null target.

Comment: Alright I got it. I just had to make it `var initial = function ()...` Thanks.

Comment: Close but it can be better. I will write up an answer describing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to perform the same set of actions in both places, simply refactor that part out:

```
function initialize() {
    // common initialization code
}

function postRender() {
    initialize();

    // more code specific to postRender
    $('#splash').removeClass('hidden');
}

window.addEventListener("load", initialize);
```

Comment: When I do this I get a null object error from a plugin that allows me to drag the screen. But if I do `var initial = function ()` it works. Not sure why it makes a difference, might be the library of the plugin.